# Why Icon is Disabled When I Set Column Background Color in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Why icon is disabled when I set column background color? When I set column background color icon is disabled.

```
@Composable
fun MyUi() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
            contentDescription = "Go back",
            modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp)
        )
    }
    // This column's background color
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White)
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(text = "Lorem ipsum")
    }
}
```

Comment: These 2 columns in which layout did you put them are they inside Box, Scaffold, Surface... It is better if you add the whole composable function

Comment: Provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In compose it's a best practice to have a single parent composable widget which wraps the composable tree.

In your case, there are 2 columns added as a parent composable. To fix the issue, combine the background and the column into a single composable.

```
@Composable
fun MyUi() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.White)) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
            contentDescription = "Go back",
            modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp)
        )

        Text(text = "Lorem ipsum")
    }
}
```